# How do I check for an image name in the database and return a static image if NULL in a Laravel Blade Template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

How do I use the Null coalescing operator to check for an image name in the database, otherwise return a static image?  The following is a line from my Laravel Blade file that I am trying to work with.

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('/images/user/'. $profile->photo ?? 'Firefighter-Silhouette.png') }}" class="rounded-circle shadow-2 img-thumbnail" alt="">
```

Not only does it not return the static image, it somehow removes the final forward slash in the '/images/user/' string.

```
<img src="https://siriusfireweb.local/images/user" class="rounded-circle shadow-2 img-thumbnail" alt="">
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

1st condition

```
 <img src="{{asset('/images/user/'. @if($profile->photo != null)
    {{ $profile->photo}}
    @else
    {{'Firefighter-Silhouette.png'}}
    @endif }}" class="rounded-circle shadow-2 img-thumbnail" alt="">
```

- you can check this code its help you to find the null return value.

2nd condition

```
@php 
if($profile->photo != null){ // you can check your condition here.
$img = asset('/images/user/'.$profile->photo);
}else{
$img = asset('/images/user/Firefighter-Silhouette.png');
}

@endphp
```

now you can use $img variable on img src